# Magento2 - Invalid header value detected

Tags: zend-framework, magento2

I am migrating magento 2.1.9 to new server which has PHP 7.0
, but after configuration it shows

```
"Invalid header value detected"
```

Please advice how to clear this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

ew release of bitweb/mail module has been done. See the difference: https://github.com/BitWeb/mail/pull/1
Please update your project, it should be fixed now.